# Trying to make `Solve` and `ReplaceAll` work together

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

I have

```
\[ScriptCapitalX][x_] := 
  \[ScriptCapitalC][1] Cos[Sqrt[λ] x] + \[ScriptCapitalC][2] Sin[Sqrt[λ] x]
```

Now, using the `Replace` function on `\[ScriptCapitalX][x_]`, I get

> ```
> BC1tospatialode = \[ScriptCapitalX][x] /. \[ScriptCapitalC][1] -> \[ScriptCapitalC][2] Sqrt[λ]
> ```

Again, applying the `Replace` function on `BC1tospatialode`, I get

```
BC1tospatialode /. x -> L
```

Here is where things gets slightly tricky in terms of the syntax:

Ideally, I would like to set

```
BC1tospatialode /. x -> L
```

to zero and solve for `λ` with `Solve`, but I am unable to circumvent the syntax.

I've tried

```
BC2BC1tospatialode = 
  Solve[
    \[ScriptCapitalC][2] Sin[Sqrt[λ] L] + 
      \[ScriptCapitalC][2] Sqrt[λ] Cos[Sqrt[λ] L] == 0, 
    λ]
```

to no avail.

Would anyone be willing to help?

Comment: It's a transcendental equation.  Assign `L` to a value and use `FindRoot`.  For L = 1, lambda =4.11586 works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't solve the equations analytically, since it is transcendental of the form `Sqrt[Lambda] == -Tan[L Sqrt[Lambda]]`

Restrict the `Lambda`values to lambdamax to get results with

```
BC2BC1tospatialode[L_,lambdamax_] := 
      NSolve[(Sqrt[lambda] Cos[L Sqrt[lambda]] \[ScriptCapitalC][2] + 
          Sin[L Sqrt[lambda]] \[ScriptCapitalC][2] /. C[2] -> 1) == 0 && 
          0 < lambda < lambdamax, lambda]

BC2BC1tospatialode[4, 50] // N

(*    {{lambda -> 0.412945}, {lambda -> 1.7916}, {lambda -> 
        4.30866}, {lambda -> 8.02989}, {lambda -> 12.9744}, {lambda -> 
        19.1481}, {lambda -> 26.5535}, {lambda -> 35.1914}, {lambda -> 
        45.0624}}    *)
```

C[2] is set to 1, since it has no influence on roots.